# Jquery cookie checkbox button refresh

Tags: jquery, cookies, checkbox, refresh

I'm using the following code to save the state of my checkboxes and it works BUT when the page is closed and reopened it doesn't keep the button clicked.

```
$(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#cabOptions').find(':checkbox'), checkboxCookieName = 'checkbox-state';
    checkbox.each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', $.cookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + $(this).attr('name')));
    });

    checkbox.click(function () {
        $.cookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + $(this).attr('name'), $(this).prop('checked'), {
            expires: 365
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2gEt/1/ ?

Comment: unfortunately no, I'm trying to do something like this `$(this).button('refresh');` but can't get it to work

Comment: which is the plugin used? jQuery UI or bootstrap

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2gEt/5/ ?

Comment: The plugin is JQuery UI. Sorry no that doesn't work.

Comment: see the updated fiddle... it is working

Comment: Just tried the updated fiddle and it still doesn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45764/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-frankn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#cabOptions').find(':checkbox'),
        checkboxCookieName = 'checkbox-state';
    checkbox.each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', $.cookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + this.name));
    });

    checkbox.button()

    checkbox.change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $.cookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + this.name, this.checked, {
                expires: 365
            });
        } else {
            $.removeCookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + this.name);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2gEt/)